# Text process using R

Tags: r, text

I am quite new in programming and R Software.

My data-set includes date-time variables as following:

```
2007/11/0103
2007/11/0104
2007/11/0105
2007/11/0106
```

I need an operator which count from left up to the character number `10` and then execute a `space` and copy the last two characters and then add :`00` for all columns.

Expected results:

```
2007/11/01 03:00
2007/11/01 04:00
2007/11/01 05:00
2007/11/01 06:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your dates are a vector named `dates`

```
library(stringr)
paste0(paste(str_sub(dates, end=10), str_sub(dates, 11)), ":00")
```

Comment: After importing the data to R, I encounter the following error regarding to the data :                                            Error: String must be an atomic vector

Answer (score 6):

If you want to actually turn your data into a `"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"` class in R (so you could subtract/add days, minutes and etc from/to it) you could do

```
# Your data
temp <- c("2007/11/0103", "2007/11/0104", "2007/11/0105", "2007/11/0106")

temp2 <- strptime(temp, "%Y/%m/%d%H")
## [1] "2007-11-01 03:00:00 IST" "2007-11-01 04:00:00 IST" "2007-11-01 05:00:00 IST" "2007-11-01 06:00:00 IST"
```

You could then extract hours for example

```
temp2$hour
## [1] 3 4 5 6
```

Add hours

```
temp2 + 3600
## [1] "2007-11-01 04:00:00 IST" "2007-11-01 05:00:00 IST" "2007-11-01 06:00:00 IST" "2007-11-01 07:00:00 IST"
```

And so on. If you just want the format you mentioned in your question (which is just a character string), you can also do

```
format(strptime(temp, "%Y/%m/%d%H"), format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
#[1] "2007/11/01 03:00" "2007/11/01 04:00" "2007/11/01 05:00" "2007/11/01 06:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(lubridate)
dat <- read.table(text="2007/11/0103
2007/11/0104
2007/11/0105
2007/11/0106",header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)

dat$V1 <- format(ymd_h(dat$V1),"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
dat
#                 V1
#  1 2007/11/01 03:00
#  2 2007/11/01 04:00
#  3 2007/11/01 05:00
#  4 2007/11/01 06:00
```

Answer (score 0):

`paste` and `substr` are your friends here. Type `?` before either to see the documentation

```
my.parser <- function(a){
  paste0(substr(a, 0,10),' ',substr(a,11,12),':00') # paste0 is like paste but does not add whitespace
}

a<- '2007/11/0103'
my.parser(a) # = "2007/11/01 03:00"
```